# WiFi on Intel NUC6i3SYH

Tags: debian, wifi, iwlwifi

I just bought an Intel NUC6i3SYH and I installed Debian Jessie on it. I couldn't get the WiFi working. I already tried installing `firmware-iwlwifi` by following [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi), but it still doesn't work. I also tried installing with the [Debian non-free installer](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/), but it also doesn't work. It also doesn't work with Lubuntu, but it works with Linux Mint. How can I get it working with Debian?

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What do the logs say?

Comment: @JennyD I tried doing [this](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi), but after that my WiFi still doesn't work. If you need the output of a command, tell me…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wireles-wiki-kernel](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) Intel® Wireless 8260 is supported by Kernel version > 4.1. To get wifi working you need to install the required firmware from backport (the easy way) or Upgrade your current kernel version.

First you need to enable backport

```
 echo deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

Then install the required firmware through the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get update  && sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports  firmware-iwlwifi
```

Comment: Which packages do I need to download with `apt-get download` on another PC? Btw I already installed `firmware-iwlwifi`…

Comment: You need to downlaod `firmware-iwlwifi` from backport

Comment: +GAD3R I tried that and it doesn't work, so what packages do I need to `apt-get download` to update the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

The Intel NUC6i3SYH has an [Intel Wireless-AC 8260 M.2](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc6i3syh.html) wireless antenna, requiring [the iwlwifi-8000-ucode firmware](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html), which does not automatically ship [with Debian Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-iwlwifi). You may simply download the firmware from the second site, unpack it with

```
tar xvf iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
```

and place one of the files thusly obtained,  `iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode`, in the directory `/lib/firmware`, reboot, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I already did that like I said…

Comment: But isn't supported by the 3.16 kernel version

Comment: Have you checked you have the exact version of the firmware above, *i.e.* `8000C-13`? That's not mentioned anywhere in your post.